# JBoss Profiler: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: java, windows, jboss, jar, profiler

I have downloaded the JBoss Profiler software package and I have followed the installation instructions.

I have moved the following files to the jboss/bin directory: 1) jboss-profiler.jar, 2) jboss profiler-plugins.jar, 3) jboss-profiler.properties, 4) javassist.jar

And the jboss-profiler.sar file to the server/deploy directory.

However, every time I issue the command:

```
java -jar jboss-profiler-client.jar startProfiler
```

I get an error:

```
Unable to access jarfile jboss-profiler-client.jar
```

I'd appreciate any help on this issue.